# In react-native-video, how do I reset the video player when the video has finished playing?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

I have a react-native app with videos that I am displaying using react-native-video. Right now when the video has finished playing you have to manually drag the control for the position of the video back to zero and then press play to have the video restart.

How can I make the video automatically reset when it has been played to the end? (Or even better, is there any way to add a replay button?)

Currently the app is only for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding repeat value equals to true in Video Component. It will do your work and video will autoplay upon ending.

```js
<Video...repeat={true}/>
```

Comment: Preferably I would want the video to stop and the video position moved to the first frame when the video reaches the end. The repeat functionality looks interesting though.